# Webpack + React: Passing arbitrary key-value configuration data into JSX

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

Pretty straightforward thing I want to do: I'm building a React app, using webpack to bundle it.  I have some properties that want to pass through, from a configuration JSON file, and be able to refer to those values in my React code.

I figured out a way to do it, though it seems like there should be a more direct way to do it.  Looking for suggestions on how to do it more cleanly.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing, and it works.

The idea is that I'm threading this value into a hidden element of the HTML, and then passing it into my main React element as props.  I'd prefer a way to pass this value directly into React props but have not been able to find a way to do that.

**properties.json**

```
{
  "myKey": "foo (possibly dynamically generated by a build step)"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const config = require(__dirname + '/properties.json');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    metadata: config
});
// ... Rest of normal-looking webpack with babel-loader and react preset
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head><!-- normal head contents --></head>
    <body>
        <!-- One of these per key-value pair in my properties -->
        <div id="config-myKey" style="display: none">
            <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.myKey %>
        </div>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

React app (index.js):

```
const Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       return(<p>This is the value for myKey: ${this.props.myKey}</p>);
    }
});

// Read in the value from the hidden HTML element, and pass it through to the
// React app as props.  This part feels like there should be a better way to
// do it.
const myValue = document.getElementById('config-myKey').innerHTML.trim();
ReactDOM.render(
    <Main myKey=${myValue}/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: If you have some values declared in a module, why won't you just import them? (am I missing something?)

Comment: I want these values to be generated by a (previous) build step.  As in, properties.json will be populated on the fly, not hardcoded.

Comment: what you're looking for is https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: Thank you @azium!  That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks @azium.

For completeness, here's exactly how I have it working now.  Much cleaner.

**properties.json**.  Note the escaped quotes; those are necessary because I want this to appear as a string literal.

```
{
  "REPLACE_ME_WITH_FOO_VALUE": "\"foo\""
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const config = require(__dirname + '/properties.json');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
   filename: 'index.html',
   inject: 'body'
});
const DefinePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin(config);

module.exports = {
   entry: [ './app/index.js' ],

   // ... Rest of normal-looking webpack with babel-loader and react preset

   plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, DefinePlugin]
});
```

**index.js**

```
const myValue = REPLACE_ME_WITH_FOO_VALUE;
ReactDOM.render(<Main myKey={myValue}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```